# Computation of Colored HOMFLY Polynomials

Tags: knot-theory, homflypt-polynomial

I am trying to understand the colored HOMFLY polynomials. The theoretic description Anna Aiston gave in her [PhD thesis](https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/%7Esu14/papers/aistonthesis.pdf) is really nice, but what about the computation?

I would like to understand the [knots-quivers correspondence](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.04017.pdf), so I would like to learn how one can compute the $S^r$-colored HOMFLY polynomials. How can the $S^r$-colored HOMFLY polynomials $\overline{P}_K$ of a given knot $K$ be computed? For example, in the easiest cases of the unknot or the trefoil, is there a certain way how to compute the formulas as stated in the paper about the knots-quivers correspondence?

In section 5.1 of the above paper, the authors give a formula for the colored HOMFLY polynomials of the unknot, but they do not mention how they have computed it.

Comment: One way is to use make use of quantum $6j$-symbols for $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_N)$. See, for instance, https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5144
In connection with knots-quivers correspondence, you might want to take a look at papers by Marko Stosic and Paul Wedrich (https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03333 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.10837)

Comment: Thank you very much! The papers by Stosic and Wedrich helped a lot. Their approach is understandable without knowledge in physics, so I was able to understand how the HOMFLY polynomials can be computed.